# How to implement view count for unregistered users?

Tags: php, mysql

I have it set up to where I log each view in a table called `question_views` so each user can only be counted once.

However, I have a problem. Right now when you're not logged in the view count just keeps incrementing because I don't have a way to identify unregistered people (or people not logged in).

This is how I enter the users into the database for when they view:

```
function add_view($user, $question) {
  $ts = time();
  $check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_views WHERE user='$user' AND question_id=$question"));
    if($check==0) {
      mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET views=views+1 WHERE qid=$question");
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO question_views (user,question_id,date) VALUES ($user,$question,$ts)");
    }
}
```

When a user isn't logged in, `$_SESSION['userid']` (which is what is passed when the function is called) doesn't even exist.

What would be a good way to make a view count system counting each viewer only once, including unregistered people?

**EDIT: Of course there isn't a way to do it reliably. But there *is* a way to do it at least somewhat good.**

Comment: There is no way to do that reliably.  You could try to use an IP address, a session, a cookie or any combination of the three.  At the end of the day though, you can't reliably.

Comment: Ok. What is the downvote for though? Whoever downvoted it, thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Nathan Would it completely break your system if you set `$_SESSION['userid'] = 'guest_' . uniqid();` so that non-logged in users are given a guest user id?  Of course one simply needs to disable cookies to get keep incrementing the view count, but that could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corbin's got it right. Personally I'd use a cookie though. IP's can be shared among several people, and sessions only last until you close your browser. I think a cookie's your best bet, but of course, it can be deleted. Just set the lifetime to 'forever' or a long interval.

Comment: Nastier solution is so called Flash cookies, because they can regenerate after removal ;-)

Comment: @Jack That's neat, but I'm an all-HTML5 guy :P The count doesn't need to be exact (and it isn't possible for it to be exact) but it also can't be incrementing every time a guest refreshes the page. I think I'll go with cookies. I was about to use a session variable since they're so simple, but cookies are better.

Comment: @Nathan I didn't say "neater", I said "nastier" :)